# tcl variable sql injection check

Tags: sql-injection, tcl

I have a tcl variable $value that is being passed through a hidden input field.
What would be a good regular expression to get it checked for an SQL injection.

I would want it to allow only numbers in case.

I would want it to allow only characters in another case.

And numbers and characters both in another case.

In all 3  cases I do not want any special chracters to be included

Comment: In general, you're recommended to use parameterized SQL statements rather than doing string substitution into SQL code; it's enormously easier to get the awkward cases right.

Comment: hi Donal ..can you give me an example of pararmeterized SQL statement using TCL/Informix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
switch $case {
  case1 {set regex {^[[:digit:]]+$}}
  case2 {set regex {^[[:alpha:]]+$}}
  case3 {set regex {^[[:alnum:][:space:]]+$}}
  default {error "what case is this?"}
}
if {! [regexp $regex $value]} {
  error "invalid value: value"
}
```

To remove non-matching chars

```
switch $case {
  case1 {set regex {\D}}
  case2 {set regex {[^[:alpha:]]}}
  case3 {set regex {[^[:alnum:][:space:]]}}
}
set safe_value [regsub -all $regex $value ""]
```

See Tcl  man pages for [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regsub.htm), and [re_syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: @glenn..instead of validating and printing the rror, what if i wanted to strip tjose special charcaters and insert? how would I go about it

Comment: also i need to allow spaces in the case 3 above. is that possible?